# Charge laptop from powerbank with lower output amps

Tags: laptop, battery, charging

I have this **Sherpa 100AC Powerbank** and I intend to purchase some ultrabook laptop that lasts long (for trips and hiking) and charges fast.

I am trying to understand all I can about Li-ion batteries before, because I want to make sure I make the best choice possible and I won't find myself with a piece of equipment that is incompatible with my power bank.

So, I will probably have to rely on the AC output *(100W, 100V, 0.9A)* for the laptop's charger but when I look at the info of most chargers I see this line that says *IN 1.2A*. What does it mean? My Sherpa says that it can only deliver *0.9A* and I want to make sure these chargers will be ok with that. Is that the maximum of amps they can draw or the minimum?

In a separate question but related to the same topic, I already have a big laptop with an AC to DC charger of *150W* (output 20V, 7.5A). The batteries inside the laptop say *48WHr*. What would happen if I connect it to the powerbank, with the laptop shut down? Will it charge until the powerbank is drained? Will it not charge? Will it charge itself from the laptop's battery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather then rely in the  Sherpas DC to AC output, get a laptop which uses less thrn 60 watts **and supports  USB PD** - this means you can use a USBC cable between the Sherpa and avoid the DC to AC to DC conversions and loss.

When Amps are quoted they are generally a maximum as is the case here. The 100 watts is an approximation of 110 volts * 0.9 amps. I would suggest against using devices that require 100 watts off this charger, but it wpuld theoretically mote-or-less work.

A charger drawing 150 watts would not work and if that much power is drawn it could damage your Sherpa. The result is unpredictable - best case thr Sherpa would shut off charging to protect itself.  (It is unlikely the laptop would push current into the Sherpa)

That said, it is entirely possible that the power supply is overrated for the laptop. A 150 watt power supply can power any device that uses less then 150 watts provided the voltage is correct. Most laptops need less then 65 watts of power unless they are high performance gaming rigs.

While you can make some educated guesses (and I would guess that the laptop is not pulling 150 watts of power based on the batteries) The WH hour rating of the battery does not tell you anything fefinitive as to the required wattage of the power supply - igniring inefficiencies, if it were 50 watt hours it means it could take 20 minutes to fully recharge at 150 watts, or 2 hours at 25 watts.  A WH is exactly that - the number if watts a battery can store and then output for an hour. Output more and it will last less then an hour, output less and it will last longer.

Comment: I know the best choice is a USB-C PD capable laptop (also because it's lighter) but, though many have a USB-C, it's hard to find one that has PD that is not over 2000 or something. Anyway, I am looking for laptops with chargers that need between 40 and 60W (many 2 in one are in this range). I am also looking into USB-C to DC adapters, just as a backup option

Comment: Just an example. I am looking at [this](https://www.asus.com/Laptops/For-Work/ExpertBook/ExpertBook-P2-P2451/techspec/) laptop with USB-C PD but its charger says 65W output. Would it work with the Sherpa that only delivers 60W output through the USB-C port?

Comment: Im a bit of a Dell Fanboi so I checked a laptop I might buy for a LOT less then $2k  - https://www.dell.com/en-us/member/shop/cty/pdp/spd/inspiron-13-7306-2-in-1-laptop?~ck=mn - and Dell advised this supports PD charging.  Double check but I **think** any laptop which supports Thunderbolt will handle USB PD charging.

Comment: Double check with ASUS, but im pretty sure it will work.  PD will negotiate the fastest compatible charge, so worst case I imagine it will charge a bit slower, but I expect it will be fine.

Comment: Thanks. That Dell looks like a good option to consider, being smaller and lighter. Don't know if it only has USB-C PD or also a DC input. The ASUS has a 65W AC to DC Adapter, in case the USB-C PD is not compatible with the powerbank. I want to have both options just to be sure